# TextView fica pra fora do RelativeLayout (com bordas arredondadas)

Tags: android, xml

Eu estou tentando fazer com que os itens da minha lista fiquem como na figura 2, porém eles só ficam como na figura 1. Pesquisei bastante a respeito, mas encontrei muito pouco a respeito (nem sei muito bem o que pesquisar).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu arquivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/lista_linhas"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_radius"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/teste"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/circulo">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/cor_esquerda" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/preto"
            android:id="@+id/numero" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/cor_direita" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

border-radius.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o `border_radius.xml`? Gostaria de testar esse layout para ver como acertar. Chegou a pensar em fazer com `Canvas`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e incluí o xml da borda arredondada. Não conheço Canvas, consigo fazer com ele?

Comment: Depende do tipo de interação que a `View` vai ter, porque com o `Canvas` você tem acesso apenas as primitivas de desenho (desenhar retângulo, quadrado, linhas, círculos, arcos, escrever texto e etc), é mais difícil trabalhar com eventos de click e etc. Se não houver alternativa, acho que tem, a solução é usar `Canvas`.

Comment: Esses desenhos funcionam como uma espécie de ícones em um ListView, precisarei trabalhar com o click deles. O uso do Canvas tornaria isso MUITO mais difícil?

Comment: Se for click na `View` inteira, não em partes, é só implementar corretamente o método `onMeasure` (onde você diz as dimensões da `View` com certas restrições baseadas no `layout_width` e `layout_height` que deu a elas), dê uma olhada em: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html, http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/ e http://blog.denevell.org/android-custom-views-onlayout-onmeasure.html.

Comment: As vezes, fazer uma `Custom View` é muito mais eficiente, porque para fazer um desenho simples você teve que usar 6 `Views` e não está bom ainda. Imagina em um `ListView` com vários elementos?

Comment: OK, obrigado. Vou dar uma olhada nesses links.

Comment: Se eu conseguir resolver o problema coloco a solução aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar uma View customizada:

```
package br.com.mion.android;

public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Rect mRect;
    private Path mPath;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRect = new Rect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // Define um path "ovalado" do tamanho da View.
        RectF r = new RectF();
        r.set(0, 0, (float) w, (float) h);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.addOval(r, Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Corta o canvas com o path "ovalado".
        canvas.clipPath(mPath);
        // Pinta o fundo de vermelho.
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

        // Desenha o retângulo vermelho da esquerda.
        mRect.set(0, 0, (int) (getWidth() * .25f), getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);

        // Desenha o retângulo vermelho da direita.
        mRect.set((int) (getWidth() * .75f), 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);

    }

};
```

E utilizar no teu arquivo de layout assim, por exemplo:

```
<br.com.mion.android.MyView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: Oi, André, bem vindo ao site. Pode explicar, ainda que brevemente, porquê seu código resolve o problema apresentado? É só [edit] a resposta. O [Tour] do site e o
 guia [answer] tem mais dicas.